# After a defined statement is executed, "none" is printed twice

Tags: python, function

When I run the following code and go through the whole `request` function and I answer `n` to the `reqSecPass` part, it prints `goodbye` followed by two lines that say `None`. How do I eliminate this?

You can see that the `goodbye` statement is on its own and I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

```
def goodbye():
    print('Good Bye!')

def request():
    reqPass = input('Which password would you like?[Google, Twitter, Reddit, Computer]')
    #still need to figure out dictionary manipulation so this is a temporary sytem.
    if(reqPass == 'google' or reqPass == 'google'):
        print('________________')
        print('Pass: GOOGLEPASSWORDHERE')
        print('________________')
        reqSecPass = input('Request another password?[y/n]')
        if(reqSecPass == 'y' or reqSecPass == 'Y'):
            print(another())
        else:
            print(goodbye())
    elif(reqPass == 'twitter' or reqPass == 'Twitter'):
        print('_________________')
        print('User: TWITTERUSERNAMEHERE')
        print('Pass: TWITTERPASSWORDHERE')
        print('________________')
        reqSecPass = input('Request another password?[y/n]')
        if(reqSecPass == 'y' or reqSecPass == 'Y'):
            print(another())
        else:
            print(goodbye())
    elif(reqPass == 'computer' or reqPass == 'Computer'):
        print('________________')
        print('Pass: COMPUTERPASSWORDHERE')
        print('________________')
        reqSecPass = input('Request another password?[y/n]')
        if(reqSecPass == 'y' or reqSecPass == 'Y'):
            print(another())
        else:
            print(goodbye())
    elif(reqPass == 'reddit' or reqPass == 'Reddit'):
        print('_________________________')
        print('User: REDDITUSERNAMEHERE')
        print('Pass: REDDITPASSWORDHERE')       
        print('________________')
        reqSecPass = input('Request another password?[y/n]')
        if(reqSecPass == 'y' or reqSecPass == 'Y'):
            print(request())
        else:
            print(goodbye())
print('_____This is a password keeper_____')
#checking if the user has an account
actCheck = input('Do you already have an account?')
if(actCheck == 'Yes' or actCheck == 'yes'):
    #asking for user's name and password
    yourUser = input('___What is your Username?___')
    yourPass = input('___What is your Password?___')
    if(yourUser == 'ari' and yourPass == 'rycbar1234'):
        dirCheck = input('Account settings?[y,n]')
        if(dirCheck == 'y' or dirCheck == 'Y'):
            print('this function is not working yet!')
            actSetCheck = input('Change username or password?')
            if(actSetCheck == 'user' or actSetCheck == 'User' or actSetCheck == 'Username' or actSetCheck == 'username'):
                yourUser = input('What would you like your new username to be?')
            elif(actSetCheck == 'pass' or actSetCheck == 'Pass' or actSetCheck == 'password' or actSetCheck == 'Password'):
                yourPass = input('What would you like your new username to be?')
        elif(dirCheck == 'n' or dirCheck == 'N'):
            print(request())
    else:
        print('Incorrect Username or password')
```

Comment: Functions that seem not to return anything return `None`, such as `goodbye`. That is, `goodbye() == None`.

Comment: The default return from a function is `None` You are printing in the function then calling the function with `print` around the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the return values of your functions. Your functions all return `None` (the default return value when you don't use an explicit `return` statement).

Remove your `print()` statements from your function calls, so instead of:

```
print(another())
# ...
print(goodbye())
# ...
print(request())
```

just use

```
another()
# ...
goodbye()
# ...
request()
```

Alternatively, have your function return a string to print:

```
def goodbye():
    return 'Good Bye!'

print(goodbye())
```

although is probably not worth using a function just to return a single string value.

Comment: Thanks! I made the edit you suggested, however, it is still printing "none" but only once now.

Comment: @AriMadian: so you have another `print()` somewhere printing a return value. I didn't scan through all your code in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the value returned by functions that have no explicit `return` statement. The value returned from such a function is `None` by default. You are printing this value.

Try using a `return` statement sometimes instead of always printing, e.g. `return 'Goodbye!'`.